# vshost32.exe has stopped working + WebBrowser within WPF app crashes

Tags: wpf, exception

I have a webbrowser control which I have used within a WPF application, 
when I browse a particular url, the browser crashes thus terminating my WPF application too.

Is there a way to catch the same exception and then recover such that, I get to continue with my WPF application. I even tried instantiating it in a different AppDomain, but I have failed, is there a way out,

Please note my IE crash happens even if I open the same website using an external IE instance.

thanks

The error trace shows something about mshtml.dll.

Exact message is

```
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mshtml.dll
Exception code: 0xc0000602
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to to catch the exception through appdomain unhandled exception. Add handler in either MainWindow.cs or App.cs constructors.

MSDN reference on [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}

void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
   //check e.ExceptionObject and e.IsTerminating           
}
```